# How can I break an url and store the key-words into database using php

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url-parsing

Like `http:webmail.wipro.com#a:?b;`

I want to break this url and store only webmail and wipro into my database. Can any one help me out with this please. Using php.

Comment: First I'd ask that you clarify what your question is: I don't know if you want the key-words (to me this implies you want variables, perhaps the 'a' and 'b'?) or the subdomain ('webmail') and domain ('wipro') stored in your database. Also, what database are you using?

Comment: i need subdomain ('webmail') and domain ('wipro') stored in my database mysql

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to retrieve the parts and then use at your will (in your case, saving them in database).

Here is a test code/output from the manual:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions. If you run something like

```
preg_match('http:(.*?).(.*?).com#a:?b;', 'http:webmail.wipro.com#a:?b;', $matches);
```

$matches[1] should say webmail and $matches[2] should contain wipro.

There is more documentation for regexes and preg_match [on the PHP site](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: it can have any option like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879683/how-can-i-break-an-url-and-store-the-key-words-into-database-using-php
if this is the case i want to store stackoverflow,questions,break,store,words,database
then how is it possible to use the same  query

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is to recognise any words at all within the URL. In this case, try this RegExp:

```
preg_match_all ('/\b(\w{4,})\b/', $url, $matches);
```

`$matches` will contain an array of all word-like strings of length 4 or more

Comment: <?php

$url="http://webmail.wipro.com";
preg_match_all ('/\b(\w{4,})\b/', $url, $matches);
$n=count($matches);
echo $n; 

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
 
 echo "Piece $i = $matches[$i] <br />";

 
}
?>

out put:
2Piece 0 = Array
Piece 1 = Array

Comment: why am i getting such output plz help me out

Comment: $matches is not containing such words of length 4

Comment: `preg_match_all` returns subarrays of inner matches as well (ie. the `..(\w{4,0})..`). The words you want are in `$matches[1]`.